# Attribution of correlations given correlation between a variable and the sum of other two variables

Tags: statistics, correlation

Given,
\begin{equation}
\rho = Corr[X1, (X2 + X3)]
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\hat{\rho} = Corr[X2, X3]
\end{equation}

where Corr[] stands for Pearson correlation, how can Corr[X1, X2] and Corr[X1, X3] be attributed such that the resulting 3x3 correlation matrix is positive semidefinite?

Let´s assume E[X1]=E[X2]=E[X3]=0 for simplicity please (E[] stands for expectation).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The correlation matrix is always positive semidefinite.

Comment: I guess there are several embedded questions. the first one would be: how can I calculate Corr[X1, X2] and Corr[XX1, X3]?. The second one is whether there is a unique solution or a set of them. The thrid one is if the result ensures that the resulting matrix build from the individual correlations of X1, X2 and X3 is semidefinite positive. It would be great if you can point me to a piece of literature around this topic to have a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to your comment's second question is that (except in extreme cases) there will be multiple solutions.

Comment: How you can calculate those correlations depends on what information you have. If the only information you have is the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2+X_3$ and the correlation between $X_2$ and $X_3$, then you can't calculate them unless $Corr(X_2, X_3) = 1$. As to your third question, I'm still not sure what you mean, as the correlation matrix is positive semidefinite for any vector of random variables.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question since I see now the answer is quite easy/straitforward.

Denoting by
\begin{equation}
\rho_{12}, \rho_{13} 
\end{equation}

the quantities of interest, and
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1,\sigma_2, \sigma_3
\end{equation}

the standard deviations of the three variables X1, X2, X3, we have that

\begin{equation}
\rho = \frac{E[X_1 (X_2 + X_3)] - E[X_1]E[X_2 + X_3]}{\sigma_1 \sqrt{\sigma_2^2 + \sigma_3^2 + 2\hat{\rho}\sigma_2 \sigma_3}}
\end{equation}

Therefore the answer is the set of pairs

\begin{equation}
\rho_{12}, \rho_{13}
\end{equation}

that fullfils

\begin{equation}
\rho = \frac{\rho_{12}\sigma_2 + \rho_{13}\sigma_3}{\sqrt{\sigma_2^2 + \sigma_3^2 + 2 \hat{\rho} \sigma_2 \sigma_3}}
\end{equation}

with
\begin{equation}
0 \leq \rho_{1,2}, \rho_{13}  \leq 1
\end{equation}

I will work more on what solutions from this set form a positive semidefinite matrix.